# GRUB/EFI - Divide & Conquer, smart multiple boot solution

Tags: linux, multi-boot, grub, efi

Is there an adequate way to partition a HDD in such a way that every Linux distribution I install has its own GRUB, so that one distro shares anything or interferes with another distro at its absolute minimum?

Comment: This question revels a misunderstanding about UEFI. With UEFI, in a multi-boot scenario, any OS has its own bootloader co-existing with all the other in the ESP (EFI System Partition). That, of course, includes Grub.

Comment: @ChanganAuto If I was an expert in it, I wouldn't ask this question. I don't want GRUB to be overwritten with every new distribution I install for a multi-boot scenario. I would rather want to have a set of pointers in a dedicated partition pointing to multiple GRUB partitions or a similar solution.

Comment: I just explained it ISN'T overwritten, ever. That's what co-exist means. At any time you can boot any installed OS directly from UEFI settings > Boot. It doesn't take an expert for this, all the ooposite, this is BASIC knowledge about the EFI boot process. You're assuming a "problem" that doesn't exist for a decade or so since UEFI replaced the old BIOS.

Comment: @ChanganAuto If people had that basic knowledge, it would be awesome... Every time I install new distribution, it changes GRUB configuration and shares the GRUB with other distributions.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It merely changes the boot order to itself as that is often the intended behavior. That said, which part of "you can boot any installed OS directly from UEFI settings > Boot" are you still not understanding?

Comment: @ChanganAuto You are not answering my question... I am looking for a solution, not an argument. I don't even know how to partition the drive as one distribution uses both the `EFI` and `/boot` partitions, while other uses a single `/boot/efi` partition.

Comment: Your question is non-question because it's about a non-problem so don't be surprised when you get a non-answer. And you're wrong again because you don't understand the basics and yet you *pretend* that you do. This *could* have been a good question when BIOS was the only firmware around and only one bootloader per drive could exist in a given system. With BIOS and MBR indeed the only way to have different bootloaders installed was to have different physical drives and install one in each.

Comment: That some distros' installers create a separated /boot partition by default (most don't) is irrelevant and immaterial. The first stage Grub is ALWAYS installed in the ESP and INDEPENDENTLY from each other.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi <- Here's a good reading as a starting point to understand UEFI, its requirements and the boot process. Although it's about a Windows and Ubuntu dual-boot the same basic concepts are applicable to any other combination of UEFI cabale OSes.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I am not even using the secure boot...

Comment: **And Secure Boot is also irrelevant and immaterial here**. If you think it does then unfortunately it only shows, once again, the extend of the lack of basic understanding you still have but pretend otherwise and insist on validation. But comments aren't for extended discussion - this is a forum, it's a Q&A -, comments are for clarification and info request, nothing else. It has been *repeatedly* clarified for you that the question is nonsesical so don't be surprised if there won't be any answer or, if there's one it'll only paraphrase what has been written in comments.

Comment: Once again, **there's NOTHING to answer here and there are no solutions for non-problems** and pointing that out isn't being "toxic". You need to learn once and for all *how* the boot process works in order to correct your wrong assumptions your question is based on. Also need to learn how to access UEFI settings, Boot menu and change the boot order to boot DIRECTLY any of the OSes already installed thus using EXCLUSIVELY their own Grub instead of using a boot option from other OS' Grub (also possible and generally not problematic in the slightest) which is what you want to happen for reasons.

Comment: And yet both the title and comments mention **EFI**. Only your last comment mentions otherwise. Are you trolling or don't have anything better to do than waste other people's time? If BIOS or Legacy mode in a modern UEFI hardware (which is stupid BTW) then the old rules for BIOS mode apply and that also was already pointed out in a previous comment: ***With BIOS and MBR indeed the only way to have different bootloaders installed was to have different physical drives and install one in each***. End of story.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I am not forcing you to waste time. I deleted that comment, it appears that both the Legacy Boot and Secure Boot are disabled. There are separated records in the UEFI menu, but they all point to the same GRUB menu.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an adequate way to partition a HDD in such a way that every
> Linux distribution I install has its own GRUB

You can keep the boot folder in root drive itself.Configure distros to have a common efi partition.That should be an ideal setup.

> so that one distro shares anything or interferes with another distro
> at its absolute minimum?

It's unclear what you mean here.Distros cannot share any info with each other on there own.If you mean the os-prober detecting other grub installation and adding the entries then you can simply turn off os-prober for each distro.Other than that you can turn off auto mount if you don't want distros to mount each other partitions.

> I don't want GRUB to be overwritten with every new distribution I
> install for a multi-boot scenario. I would rather want to have a set
> of pointers in a dedicated partition pointing to multiple GRUB
> partitions or a similar solution.

In uefi systems grub doesn't overwrite anything.Assuming you keep boot directory in root drive itself and have a common efi partition for all distros , each distro will just create a grub.efi in there own folder in efi partition.

This is the content of my efi (Arch linux)

[image]

For the other part -- what you are looking for is a Boot Manager

[refind](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) - it will help you manage/boot desired ditro easily

[image]

> Every time I install new distribution, it changes GRUB configuration
> and shares the GRUB with other distributions.

One distro cannot share grub configurations with any other distro's grub.It's never possible.Each grub has it's configuration of it's own stored in boot directory.And that's why boot directory is never shared between distros.

> how to partition the drive as one distribution uses both the EFI and
> /boot partitions, while other uses a single /boot/efi partition

EFI partition needs to be mounted in boot directory.Boot directory can be on another partition too.Installers of different distros have option to create a separate boot partition.You can do either way.

> There are separated records in the UEFI menu, but they all point to
> the same GRUB menu.

I can't say for sure but it should point to different grub installations or maybe it can be due to buggy firmware {attach the output of efibootmgr -v}.Attach some screenshots and content of your efi partition.Also the partition structure

I tried answering your questions, if you still wanna ask anything feel free to comment.Also accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: In other words, I can have multiple `/boot` partitions, but only one `FAT32 EFI` partition, correct?

Comment: @Andrew yes that's correct

Comment: Why don't I have multiple EFI partitions? Wouldn't UEFI take care of them?

Comment: @Andrew in theory UEFI should be taking care of that but it's generally not suggested.Many firmware just detect only one efi partition on a drive and leaves rest undetected or you might face issues like not all of them show up in uefi boot menu.if you are willing to have multiple efi partitions, i will suggest you to use refind boot manager - install refind on first efi partition , it will take care of all efi you have

Comment: But then it seems like the only way to really separate the distros is by having a separate EFI partition for each one. That way the `sudo grub update` will not interfere with anything else apart from the GRUB of the running distribution. This way I would have multiple separated GRUB instances instead of a shared one. It feels more like emulating multi-HDD scenario... True?

Comment: And I do believe that there is no such thing as "ideal setup". It all depends on a goal to achieve, especially in the world of Unix-derived systems.

Comment: Would be cool if I can place even the boot loader on a separate EFI partition...

Comment: @Andrew sudo grub update is basically grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg : it will only update the boot config of current linux distro buing used; it never touches any other distro files even if you have common efi {that's pointless as config are not stored there}; and no we are not emulating anything here; yeah linux gives complete flexibility but when using gui installers it's get limited {installers expect the user to setup in a particular way - that is what i call a ideal setup}; bootloader is always in efi partition, what do mean by other ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant installing another Linux distribution by side, that's where the GRUB gets modified, including other distribution's boot parameters.

Comment: Would be cool to place the `refind` boot loader on a first EFI partition for it to point to other EFI partitions with separated GRUBs of Linux distributions. Would it not?

Comment: Or wait... There is another layer called UEFI, right? That's the layer which takes care of the separation. And whenever I install another OS by side, it simply makes UEFI to point to it first. And it's not the GRUB what changes, it's the UEFI pointing to another GRUB of the newly installed distro. LOL)

Comment: @Andrew can you explain how you think boot loader gets modified after installing the other distros {add that as an edit to your question}; yes you can place refind that way - will work

Comment: #Madhubala Please read my last comment, it changes direction. If that's indeed the case, there is no point to have a second EFI partition trying to separate what has already been separated.

Comment: In other words, simply `UEFI` –> `FAT32 EFI` partition –> `ext2 /boot` partition, where UEFI is the main menu which is not on a hard drive.

Comment: And without root mount point encryption, there is no need to make a separate `/boot` partition. But I guess even with full encryption the `/boot` partition may still be on a root mount point.

Comment: @Andrew if you have furthur queries; ask them in as new question; also mark the answer as accepted

Comment: #Madhubala Let me first check if my last statements are correct, then I will close the question. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Andrew yeah that's correct , you can have it either way - without encrypted boot : https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Preparing_non-boot_partitions; or can have encrypted boot https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Encrypted_/boot ; hope it's clear ):